# Joomla - Login system message "Login successful"

Tags: joomla, controller, content-management-system

I'm trying to get rid of the default system message "Login successful" once the user logs in.
I just can't find where this message is enqueued! :O

Disabling or hiding the system message module is no solution for me.

Can someone help me out?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I was just looking for this message. With a clean Joomla 3 installation I can't see this message. Where do you see it? Do you have additional plugins installed which cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla stores messages like that in language files. Take a search through `administrator/language` and you will find the reference to it there.